# How to disable Secure Boot on an Acer Aspire 3 laptop?

Tags: bios, acer-aspire, secure-boot

I have a new laptop: Acer Aspire 3, model A315-51-318M.

I can enter BIOS by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> at laptop startup.

On the Boot tab there is the Secure Boot enabled and I need to disable it.

The problem is the item is grayed out and also on Security tab there are most of the items grayed out by the way.

What needs to be done for me to change these item values?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## TL;DR

Just set up the Supervisor Password and the item will become available.

You will now be prompted for a password when entering BIOS.

You can get rid of that once you have made your changes.

## Specific steps

1. Completely shut down your laptop.
2. Power on the system and as soon as the first logo screen appears, immediately press <kbd>F2</kbd> to enter the BIOS.
3. Use the right arrow key to select Security tab.
4. Use the down arrow key to highlight Set Supervisor Password and press Enter.
5. Type some password and press Enter. **Don't forget the password you enter!**
6. Retype the password to confirm and press Enter again.
7. Use the right arrow key to select Boot tab.
8. Press the down arrow key to select Secure Boot and press Enter.
9. With the arrow key, highlight Disabled and press Enter.
10. Press the <kbd>F10</kbd> key and select Yes to save the changes and exit the BIOS.

Comment: After the step 7. I don't get the "Secure Boot".

Comment: @IvanAracki Without knowing many details of your specific Aspire 3 model and its BIOS, I'm afraid I can't be of any assistance and you should [ask a new question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Note that if you clear the password, even though secure boot remains disabled, USB drives no longer show up.